# Is it possible with MySQL to have a database-specific Master Binary Log setup?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Is it possible for me to have a unique binary log per MySQL database on my MySQL server?  I've done some googling and can't seem to find any solutions.  Surely there's a way!!

Comment: What would your reasons be behind wanting to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acutally, there is a way, but it takes some work if you really require it.

[I already posted something about 6 months ago describing how to set up a Star Topology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273043/mysql-in-star-topology/5781504#5781504).

You can use the same concept. Here is the scenario

For this example, you have three databases: members, dbblogs, reports.

#### Step 01) Setup Binary Logging on the Master

If binary logging in not enabled, you can enable it

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

Restart mysql after adding `log-bin=mysql-bin` to /etc/my.cnf

#### Step 02) Setup MySQL Instance datadir for Each Specfic Database

```
mkdir /database_binlogs
mkdir /database_binlogs/members
mkdir /database_binlogs/dbblogs
mkdir /database_binlogs/reports
mkdir /database_binlogs/members/mysql
mkdir /database_binlogs/dbblogs/mysql
mkdir /database_binlogs/reports/mysql
cp /var/lib/mysql/mysql/* /database_binlogs/members/mysql
cp /var/lib/mysql/mysql/* /database_binlogs/dbblogs/mysql
cp /var/lib/mysql/mysql/* /database_binlogs/reports/mysql
chown -R mysql:mysql /database_binlogs
```

#### Step 03) [Create a MySQL Service for Each Database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/running-multiple-instances-on-the-same-host/6375#6375)

Make sure each config file has the following:

/etc/my3307.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=9993307
datadir=/database_binlogs/members
replicate-do-db=members
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-slave-updates
```

/etc/my3308.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=9993308
datadir=/database_binlogs/dbblogs
replicate-do-db=dbblogs
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-slave-updates
```

/etc/my3309.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=9993309
datadir=/database_binlogs/reports
replicate-do-db=reports
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-slave-updates
```

#### Step 04) Start the three services

- `service mysql3307 start`
- `service mysql3308 start`
- `service mysql3309 start`

#### Step 05) Perform mysqldump of database schema only from the Master, no data

Do not include mysql schema !!!

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --master-data=1 --routines --triggers --no-data --databases members dbblogs reports > /root/MySQLSchema.sql
echo "RESET MASTER; START SLAVE;" >> /root/MySQLSchema.sql
```

#### Step 06) Edit /root/MySQLSchema.sql to use only the [*BLACKHOLE storage engine*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html)

In vi, run these two replaces in the file /root/MySQLSchema.sql:

- `1,$s/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=BLACKHOLE/g`
- `1,$s/ENGINE=InnoDB/ENGINE=BLACKHOLE/g`

#### Step 07) Create a Replication User on the Master

```
GRANT SELECT,REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'replicant'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'replpass';
```

#### Step 08) Setup the 3 MySQL Instances as Slaves to Master using

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST='127.0.0.1',
MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER='replicant',
MASTER_PASSWORD='replpass',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=1;
```

#### Step 09) Load MySQL Schema into the three MySQL Instances

```
mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1 -P3307 < /root/MySQLSchema.sql
mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1 -P3308 < /root/MySQLSchema.sql
mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1 -P3309 < /root/MySQLSchema.sql
```

Binary logs are Cleared in the three Instances and Replication is started

From there, Each DB instance will record only its designated database's binlog entries

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2011-10-20 15:37 EDT**

Please keep in mind that the three slaves will contain only binlogs and not data.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can filter the binary log afterwards using `mysqlbinlog --database=...`

Comment: Beware though, as filtering will probably not give what you expect ( as stated by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_database )

While db_name is the default database, statements are output whether they modify tables in db_name or a different database.

Unless db_name is selected as the default database, statements are not output, even if they modify tables in db_name.

Comment: @Pierre-AlexisdeSolminihac Beware of what?

Comment: the caveat @pierre-alexis-de-solminihac was pointing out by linking the relevant section in the docs is: in statement-,row-level or "mixed" based binlogs, you can get different outputs depending on how the queries were issued. Users deciding to use the option should read it first and know the kind of queries their application issues.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `log_bin=` is a global MySQL variable. You can turn logging on or off per database with the `binlog-do-db=` and `binlog-ignore-db=` options, but log file location is global per server.